# Thread Synchronization with BlockingQueue in Java

Tags: java, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I am new to the concept of a BlockingQueue, and was under the impression that it took out the need for wait() and notify(). I have written the following code as a preliminary test of thread synchronization (omitting some code for clarity):

```
q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<flight>();

generator = new EventGenerator(q,flight);
southwest = new Airline(q);

new Thread(generator).start();
new Thread(southwest).start();
```

With the producer class EventGenerator. EventGenerator takes a flight from its initial state (SC) through all of the states until it reaches the gate, AG:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class EventGenerator implements Runnable
{
private final BlockingQueue<flight> bqueue;
private final flight f;

EventGenerator(BlockingQueue<flight> q, flight f1)
{
    bqueue = q;
    f = f1;
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while (f.state != "AG") { bqueue.put(produce()); }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

flight produce()
{
    if (f.state.equals("SC")){ f.state = "BD"; }
    else if (f.state.equals("BD")) { f.state = "LG"; }
    else if (f.state.equals("LG")) { f.state = "TO"; }
    else if (f.state.equals("TO")) { f.state = "LD"; }
    else if (f.state.equals("LD")) { f.state = "AG"; }

    return f;
}
```

The consumer class Airline is to receive each change in the state of a flight, and print it:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Airline implements Runnable
{
    private final BlockingQueue<flight> bqueue;

    Airline(BlockingQueue<flight> q)
    {
        bqueue = q;
    }

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while (!bqueue.isEmpty()) { consume(bqueue.take());} 
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

void consume(flight f)
{
    System.out.println("Flight no. " + f.flightno + " is now in state " + f.state);
}
}
```

The project compiles and runs without error. However, I expected (and want) the result to be something to the tune of:

```
Flight no. 1 is now in state SC
Flight no. 1 is now in state BD
Flight no. 1 is now in state LG
Flight no. 1 is now in state TO
Flight no. 1 is now in state LD
Flight no. 1 is now in state AG
```

But instead, I almost always get:

```
Flight no. 1 is now in state AG
Flight no. 1 is now in state AG
Flight no. 1 is now in state AG
Flight no. 1 is now in state AG
Flight no. 1 is now in state AG
```

Have I implemented the BlockingQueue incorrectly?

Comment: A) don't use lower case letters for class names B) you never initialize `flight` anywhere - this code would throw an NPE. C) You're using `!=` to compare strings in your while loop which is the reason for the output.

Comment: A) I couldn't figure out how to edit my typo in Eclipse, it wouldn't let me change it without changing the file name. B) I omitted that because the initialization is lengthy. C) True, thanks.

Comment: To rename your class (and its file) in Eclipse, right click, Refactor->Rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having at the moment is actually with the `produce` method. You are changing the state of the same object and placing it on the queue multiple times. What you want to do is actually place a modified copy onto the queue. If your `Flight` object were immutable, then you wouldn't encounter this issue.

Aside from the above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013991/122207) is also correct about the problems with the conditions in your while loops.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (f.state != "AG") { bqueue.put(produce()); }

while (!bqueue.isEmpty()) { consume(bqueue.take());}
```

I suspect both your `while` conditions are not really what you want: The first one should use `.equals()` for string comparison. The second *assumes* that the consumer will execute after the producer (and that the consumer is *slower* than the producer); Otherwise the consumer will find the queue empty and skip the whole loop.